# Criando página de Logs

Tags: php, mysql, log

Criei no meu Banco de Dados uma tabela `usr_logs` com as seguintes colunas:

- id
- email
- ip
- time
- date
- sucess

Só esses registros são suficientes, ou preciso acrescentar mais algo?

Como faço para exibir todos os dados inseridos nessa tabela?

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Queres a tabela `user_logs` para que? Logins? ou Log de erros?

Comment: @Paulo Pimentel isso é login ou log??? "logs" são diferentes de "logins"

Comment: São logs, registros de usuários do meu sistema, quero criar a página de logs, onde eu irei acompanhar os logs pela página e não pelo SQL, onde somente eu terei permissão de acesso a essa página, entendeu?

Answer (score 3):

Os campos que vai colocar é opcional e depende do que exatamente você quer armazenar, mas acredito que falta o principal um campo para informar o que aconteceu (uma mensagem no log para você identificar do que se trata aquele registro, pois no momento você só identifica que algo aconteceu). Dependendo do tipo de log você poderia ter um campo a mais para saber qual o tipo de log (WARNING, ERROR, NOTICE ou outros que você venha atribuir), se julgar necessário pode ainda colocar o nome da classe, nome do método ou função, nome do arquivo e número da linha isso ajudaria na hora de depurar e você pode liberar diferentes visualizações dessa tabela usando view, assim seria possível você ter uma tabela completa para depurar e mostrar uma mais simples para alguém apenas poder acompanhar o ocorrido e se teve erro ou não, poderia inclusive adicionar o usuário que estava usando a aplicação quando ocorreu o erro, versão do código. Para exibir os dados inseridos é simples basta conectar no banco de dados e extrair os dados em tela. Eu aconselho muito o uso do [jQuery.DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) pela facilidade de implementação, documentação e funcionalidade, isso se for exibir esses dados na Web, se for aplicação desktop você pode usar um Data Grid presente na linguagem de programação.

[Nesse link você vai encontrar um exemplo completo de implementação do datatable com php](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) o uso é bem simples para usar você vai precisar do plugin do datatable e jquery, se desejar ainda pode aplicar o boostraps nele. Existem outros formas essa é apenas uma delas.

Alguns campos que podem ser adicionados (tudo isso é opcional e vai da necessidade de cada um)

- classname
- methodname
- functionname
- line
- filename
- message
- review
- user_id
- type

Comment: Ok amigo, irei dar uma estudada e te dou um retorno aqui,.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar da resposta do @Sileno Brito estar bem legal,
eu sou fã do componente [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) onde você pode informar
`email`, `ip`, `sucess` como parte do `context` e o `datetime` já é gerado pelo mesmo componente, e então armazenar o output no formato que achar melhor.

A cada gravação de Log, você informará o tipo de log (WARNING, ERROR, NOTICE ...)